# Check xpath available in the browser or not

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to check the xpath available in the browser or not.
How can i check
`xpath = '//img' driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()`

What's the way to check it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)

Comment: What do you mean by availability ?

Comment: You need to give more dateless for proper understanding. Actually what you want to do?

Comment: I want to check if Xpath is available in the browser or not.

Comment: You can go to developer tool in chrome and then element and then CTRL + F and search for your xpath there. If you want to do it programmatically which is not the right approach let me know

Comment: Yes. I want to do it with selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use it:**

```
xpath = "//img"
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
    print("xpath found and clicked")
```

Comment: This is not about click

Comment: I think he want to click something. That's why he use it`driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have some xpath : `//div[@role='some role']`

In Selenium I would do this :

```
 try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='some role']")) > 0:
        print("xpath is present")
    else:
     print("xpath is not present")
except:
    pass
```